# Boto3 S3 client returns weird information when used with multi thread

Tags: python, multithreading, amazon-s3, boto3, wsl-2

I have created an application that writes the metadata information from objects inside an S3 bucket

```
s3_client = boto3.client("s3")
MAX_WORKERS = 16

def write_metadata(payload):
   metadata = s3_client.get_object(Bucket=payload[0], Key=payload[1])['Metadata']
   file.write(json.dumps(metadata)+'\n')

if __name__ == '__main__': 
   with open(file_name, 'w+', newline='') as file:
      with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=MAX_WORKERS) as executor:
         executor.map(write_metadata, payloads)
```

But in the middle of the created file I have rows with the following information like the following:

> unitrust1%0#Uuca extended validation rootq!
> �j�r�4|WNV>y�);l���mM�5߮��$�yE����ވ]%|�dg

I have run this code a thousand times, but know this is appearing
I am using WSL 2 with Ubuntu

Comment: It's in the metadata I guess. If you don't want to have it, remove it before `json.dump()`.

Comment: Your code doesn't look correct, as it doesn't guarantee thread safe access to the file. This is what you first need to look at.